# Failed to find debug token & application author does not match debug token author

Tags: debugging, cordova, blackberry-10

I'm trying to launch a BlackBerry10 phonegap application but am getting the following errors:

```
C:\sites\Safe\platforms\blackberry10\cordova>run
[BUILD]   Populating application source
[BUILD]   Parsing config.xml
[BUILD]   Generating output files[WARN]    Failed to find debug token. If you ha
ve an existing debug token, please copy it to %HOME%/.cordova/blackberry10debugt
oken.bar. To generate a new debug token, execute the 'run' command.
[INFO]    Info: Package created: C:\sites\Safe\PLATFO~1\BLACKB~1\build\simulator
\DEFAULT_BAR_NAME.bar
[WARN]    Failed to find debug token. If you have an existing debug token, pleas
e copy it to %HOME%/.cordova/blackberry10debugtoken.bar. To generate a new debug
 token, execute the 'run' command.
[INFO]    Info: Package created: C:\sites\Safe\PLATFO~1\BLACKB~1\build\device\DE
FAULT_BAR_NAME.bar
[BUILD]   BAR packaging complete
[INFO]    Info: Sending request: Install and Launch
[INFO]    Info: Action: Install and Launch
[INFO]    Info: File size: 1704050
[INFO]    Info: Installing default.app.id.testDev_ault_app_id417e7455...Info: Pr
ocessing 1704050 bytes
[INFO]    actual_dname::actual_id::
[INFO]    actual_version::result::failure 881 application author does not match
debug token author
```

My device has a valid debug token and the author matches the author in the config.xml. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Your question provided my answer since your warning was more detailed than the one I got. When I copied my debug token from its usual location in:

c:\Users\\AppData\local\Research In Motion\169.254.0.1debugtoken.bar

to

c:\Users\.cordova\blackberry10debugtoken.bar

this fixed both the warning and the error and the app deployed to my device.